# Split Dataset into smallers sets randomly f#

Tags: f#

I am learning F # and I would like to learn how to split a data set into 10 smaller sets randomly. Anyone have any ideas to start ??? What topic should I read ??? I need help to continue. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output and also input. You should start with [F# for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/) and the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/). Especially for the collection related functions.

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on what exactly it is that you want to achive. You can use the `Permute` function of most collections. Here is an example that takes advantage of the `MathNet.Numerics` to generate the random indexes and then shuffles the data. Of course you can first split and then shuffle the date as well. And use `Array.permute` instead. Just nuget MathNet.Numerics and MathNet.Numerics.FSharp.

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r @"../packages/MathNet.Numerics/lib/net461/MathNet.Numerics.dll"
#r @"../packages/MathNet.Numerics.FSharp/lib/net45/MathNet.Numerics.FSharp.dll"
#endif

open System
open MathNet.Numerics

let rnd = System.Random()
let randomData = Array.init 100 (fun _ -> rnd.Next()) // generate the initial data 
let randomIndex =  (Combinatorics.GeneratePermutation 100) // create a random index

randomIndex
|> Array.map (fun x -> randomData.[x]) //shuffle the data
|> Array.splitInto 10 //split it into 10 subsets
```

Your result will be, in this case, an `int` array of arrays. It's more idiomatic to use Lists in F#. Also if your data is very large you might consider using `Seq` which is lazy.